Business Address Change in Germany
We are going to change our office address from Kaiserslautern to Munich. If we do this, will we get a new Tax ID?

No, that is the whole point of having an alphanumeric ID:
The name of a business, its registered address, or anything else may change, the ID still identifies the same business.
